# Google Fit: How to Use Multiple Data Sources, and onDataPoint not being called

Tags: android, google-fit

I been playing around with the Google FIT API, so I can read the total steps taken, steps being taken, distance covered, total calories and so on. When I run the app, nothing seems to happen. I thought in order to receive data from each category, you would need to create a separate datapoint listener for each. These don't seem to be invoked - I am not getting any toasts with updated values.

Here is my code:

```
private void getFitnessDataSources()
{
    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(googleApiClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(dataTypes[0]).setDataTypes(dataTypes[1]).setDataTypes(dataTypes[2])
            .setDataTypes(dataTypes[3]).setDataTypes(dataTypes[4]).setDataTypes(dataTypes[5])
            .setDataTypes(dataTypes[6]).setDataTypes(dataTypes[7])
            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
        @Override public void onResult(@NonNull DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {

                 for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                    displayToast("Data source found: "+dataSource.getName());

                     if (dataSource.getDataType() == dataTypes[0]) {
                        caloriesListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                                for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                    Value fieldValue = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                    displayToast("Field Name: "+field.getName() + "Value: " +
                                            ""+fieldValue);
                                    totalTimeTextView.setText(fieldValue.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        };
                         registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, dataTypes[0], caloriesListener);
                     } else if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(dataTypes[1])) {
                        currentCaloriesListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                                for (Field field: dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                    Value fieldValue = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                    displayToast("Field Name: "+field.getName()+"Value: "+fieldValue);
                                    distanceCoveredTextView.setText(fieldValue.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        };
                         registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, dataTypes[1], currentCaloriesListener);
                     } else if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(dataTypes[2])) {
                        stepCountsListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                                for (Field field: dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                    Value fieldValue = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                    displayToast("Field Name: "+field.getName()+"Value: "+fieldValue);

                                }
                            }
                        };
                         registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, dataTypes[2], stepCountsListener);
                     } else if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(dataTypes[3])) {
                         totalStepCountsListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                                 for (Field field: dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                     Value fieldValue = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                     displayToast("Field Name: "+field.getName()+"Value: "+fieldValue);
                                 }
                             }
                         };
                         registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, dataTypes[3], totalStepCountsListener);

                     } else if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(dataTypes[4])) {
                         distanceListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                                 for (Field field: dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                     Value fieldValue = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                     displayToast("Field Name: "+field.getName()+"Value: "+fieldValue);
                                 }
                             }
                         };
                         registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, dataTypes[4], distanceListener);
                     } else if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(dataTypes[5])){
                         totalDistanceListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                                 for (Field field: dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                     Value fieldValue = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                     displayToast("Field Name: "+field.getName()+"Value: "+fieldValue);
                                 }
                             }
                         };
                         registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, dataTypes[5], totalDistanceListener);
                     } else if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(dataTypes[6])) {
                         speedListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                                 for (Field field: dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                     Value fieldValue = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                     displayToast("Field Name: "+field.getName()+"Value: "+fieldValue);
                                 }
                             }
                         };
                         registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, dataTypes[6], speedListener);
                     } else if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(dataTypes[7])) {
                         speedSummaryListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                                 for (Field field: dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                     Value fieldValue = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                     displayToast("Field Name: "+field.getName()+"Value: "+fieldValue);
                                 }
                             }
                         };
                         registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, dataTypes[7], speedSummaryListener);
                     }
                 }
        }
    });
}
```

This is code that initializes the data types array I am making use of:

```
private void initializeSessionDataTypes()
{
    dataTypes = new DataType[] {DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType
            .TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType
            .TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE, DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType
            .AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.TYPE_SPEED, DataType.AGGREGATE_SPEED_SUMMARY};
}
```

This is code I am using to register each fitness data source:

```
private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType,
                                         OnDataPointListener listener) {
    Fitness.SensorsApi.add(googleApiClient, new SensorRequest.Builder().setDataSource
            (dataSource).setDataType(dataType).setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build(),
            listener).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                displayToast("Listener is registered");
            } else {
                displayToast("Listener is not registered");
            }
        }
    });
    subscribeToFitnessData(dataType);
}
```

My google API client:

```
private void buildFitnessApi() {

    Scope activityRead = new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ);
    Scope fitnessActivityReadWrite = new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE);
    Scope bodyRead = new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ);
    Scope bodyReadWrite = new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE);
    Scope locationRead = new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ);
    Scope locationReadWrite = new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE);

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this.getActivity()).addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API).addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API).addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API)
                        .addApi(Fitness
                        .RECORDING_API).addScope(activityRead).addScope
                        (fitnessActivityReadWrite).addScope(bodyRead).addScope(bodyReadWrite)
                .addScope(locationRead).addScope(locationReadWrite)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
}
```

Can someone help me? What would be the best way to make use of the google fit api if youre trying to get multiple data streams (Step count, calories burnt, etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need that many else if statements for different datasources. I would just call registerFitnessDataListener on each datasource, and you need this piece of code before adding the listeners using SensorsAPI...

```
final DataType dataType = dataSource.getDataType();
    if (dataType.equals(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA) ||
            dataType.equals(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED) ||
            dataType.equals(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA) ||
            dataType.equals(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)){
```

I suspect that the problem lies in registering multiple onDataPointListeners for multiple datasources. I've tested it out, and the result is:
Since each onDataPointListener has this onDataPoint method

```
@Override
                        public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                            for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                Value fieldValue = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                                displayToast("Field Name: "+field.getName() + "Value: " +
                                        ""+fieldValue);
                                totalTimeTextView.setText(fieldValue.toString());
                            }
                        }
```

the last (or could be the first) onDataPointerListener being registered is only being able to listen to the data points received, thus the OnDataPoint methods for the other listeners not being called.

So, this is a concurrency problem, and we should create a thread for each listener. I don't know how to do it, but I hope someone else can help us.